# If I install an SSL certificate for my domain, will it include email ssl?

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, domains

I will be purchasing a rapidSSL certificate for mydomain.com.

I'm running WHM/Cpanel on top of a CentOS system.
Web server is Apache.

What I want to know is if I purchase the regular (non wildcard) certificate, will it enable secure email for my domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want to know is if I purchase the regular (non wildcard) certificate, will it enable secure email for my domain?

The same SSL certificate can be used to secure multiple services.  Whether or not this will work for you depends on how you use it and how your environment is configured.  For example, if you are running your own mail server at `mydomain.com`, you should be able to configure your mail software to use your certificate and have it function as expected, assuming that all of your users connect to `mydomain.com` for SMTP (or POP or IMAP) service.

If you use different hostnames for different services, you will need either a wildcard certificate or an individual certificate for each hostname.

Comment: So, a certificate for mydomain.com will secure smtp.mydomain.com and pop.mydomain.com?
Or do I need a wildcard for that?

Comment: @hitautodestruct You need either a wildcard certificate, or a certificate which allows you to add additional domain names to it, such as a so-called "unified communications" certificate. The actual name of this feature is _subject alternate name_.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks. No clear answer for this anywhere.

Comment: *So, a certificate for mydomain.com will secure smtp.mydomain.com and pop.mydomain.com?* No, a certificate for `mydomain.com` will only secure `mydomain.com`.  For other names, you will need either multiple certificates, a wildcard certificate, or, as Michael says, a certificate with *subject alternative names*.

Answer (score 0):

You will either need a wildcard or SAN (UC) certificate. I bought a certificate from SSL.com and it added a www. in front of my domain for imap.domain.com so it worked for www.imap.domain.com. I talked to their support through chat and they told me if I want to secure imap.domain.com and www.domain.com, I would have to go with wildcard or if it's only 2 domains, the multi domain UC certificate was more economical.

Comment: This should really go into a comment, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: Are you here just to spam ssl.com? It's worth noting that such behavior really presents the vendor in a bad light.

Answer (score 0):

It is standard to request a certificate domain.com and the issuer will include [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) but anything else requires a wildcard certificate. Clearly something like imap.www.domain.com is not what is intended. I suggest setting up a LetsEncrypt certificate for your other services. Also certificates used to be relatively expensive but the price for certs at NameCheap seem reasonable, and if still active you can move the cert, eg. cancel and reissue, a nice feature.